# How to specify user restrictions in domain driven design?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

How to specify restrictions to user in domain driven.

I am using asp.net web api application  and that application service uses from web api.

```
[ApiController]
public class TicketController : ControllerBase
{
    ....
    ....
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("change-date")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeTicketDate(TicketChangeCommand command)
    {
        var response = await _ticketService.ChangeTicketDate(command, User.Identity.Name);

        return Ok(response);
    }
    ....
    ....

}
```

To prevent the tickets, I am sending the authenticated username to _ticketService. Because a user may change another user ticket. So I have two rules for ticket date change logic.

1- User should be owner of ticket.
2- Or User sholud be in Administrator role.

(These rules also will be using other services. For example User can only change his own password.)

```
public class TicketService : ITicketService
{
    ....

    public TicketChange ChangeTicketDate(TicketChangeCommand command, string requestedUsername){
            // 1. Check requested user is ticket creator or Administrator               
    }

    ....
}
```

To check the user role and owner, should I create a domain service? Should I create a domain authorization service to check roles?

Comment: I think it is indeed good practice to make a seperate service for this. but this is not domain driven design. it's more related to solid principles if anything

Comment: I agree, question is unrelated to DDD at all. But have a look at [Resource-based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-3.0) on how to use policies for that

Answer (score 0):

As I see this in DDD you should have some method in your DomainModel class to do this operation e.g. `ChangeTicketDate`

Now if you store the information of the ticket creator when you create the ticket "**which I believe you do**" the validation should be part of DomainModel itself e.g.
`ChangeTicketDate(string userName)`

then the DomainService "Or ApplicationService" should just pass this value to the Domain Model class and the validation should be in the Domain Class

However, in some cases you may need to implement some validations before the domain model or let's say it's not related to the Entity itself, those validations should be in your Application Service

*I guess the following piece of code will explain my idea better*

```
public class TicketService : ITicketService
{
    // .... 
    // I expect that you'll be able to get some information about the current user


    public CurrentUserData CurrentUser {get; private set;}

    public TicketChange ChangeTicketDate(TicketChangeCommand command){
            // 1. Load the Aggregate Root from the Data StoreCheck
            var ticket = db.GetById(ticketId);

            // 2. Do some Application level checks
            // 3. Check if the current user is Admin
            if(CurrentUser.IsAdmin)
                ticket.ChangeTicketDate();
            else    
                ticket.ChangeTicketDate(CurrentUser.Username);
    }
    ....
}


//Example of Domain Model class
public class Ticket : Entity<Guid>
{
    public UserInfo Creator {get; private set;}

    public void ChangeTicketDate(string requestedUsername){
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedUsername) && requestedUsername != Creator.UserName)
                threw new ValidationException("You're not allowed to do ChangeTicketDate");
    }
    ....
}
```